# How can i query Azure for resources using Powershell with multiple query options?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am query for resources in a subscription as follows:

```
(az resource list --subscription <subscription-id> --query "[? 
type=='Microsoft.Web/sites'] "| ConvertFrom-Json)
```

But i want to put a second query parameter like the following

```
(az resource list --subscription <subscription-id> --query "[? 
type=='Microsoft.Web/sites'&& resourcegroup== $resourcegroup.name ]"| 
 ConvertFrom-Json)
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Why not use `Search-AzGraph` with KQL query?

Comment: i am using az command set at the moment .. is there a way i can do it ?

Comment: no idea how to do it with Az CLI. With the cmdlet I mentioned above is really easy using a Kusto query

Comment: I am using the Az CLI as Microsoft says this is the way to go in the future

Comment: resource graph query would be done? Do you want in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For querying multiple parameters you can use az graph query in azure cli as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli):

Firstly, Set account subscription as below:

```
az account set --name "XX"
```

XX- Subscription name.

Now query to get resources:

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type=~ 'microsoft.web/sites' | project resourceGroup, name"| ConvertFrom-Json
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try by using the [`Pipe expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts%2Cbash#pipe-expressions) (`|`) to separate each condition. Your command would be something like:

```
(az resource list --subscription <subscription-id> --query "[? 
type=='Microsoft.Web/sites'] | [?resourceGroup=='$resourcegroup.name']" | 
 ConvertFrom-Json)
```

Please ensure that you are using proper casing for property names (e.g. `resourceGroup` instead of `resourcegroup`) and string values are inside single quotes.

Here's the command I used to get storage accounts in a resource group in my Azure Subscription:

```
az resource list --query "[? type=='Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'] | [?resourceGroup=='my-resource-group-name']"
```

Comment: I assume the and condition will be && ?

Comment: So really im getting all app services in a resource group. Is there an easier way

Comment: What I used was sequential filtering. First get all storage accounts and then find storage accounts in a resource group.